# Conditional cumulative sum with dependency in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I'm trying to calculate two cumulative sums given a series of financial transactions. There are 4 transactions types, each with an amount for the transaction:
D - deposit
W - withdraw
G - gain
L - loss

The data frame is created like so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = { 'Type': ['D', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'L', 'W', 'G', 'W', 'G', 'L' ],
         'Amount': [10, 10, -5, 10, 5, 5, 5, -5, -10, 10, -25, 25, -30]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Type', 'Amount'])
```

The running Capital is easy to calculate using the cumsum(), which essentially includes all transactions.

```
df['Capital'] = df['Amount'].cumsum()
```

The other entity I want to calculate is the Principal, which represents the amount of money is input into the account. This only considers D and W type transactions. I can do a simple filter here using:

```
df['Principal'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['Amount'] if (row['Type'] == 'W' or row['Type'] == 'D') else 0, axis=1).cumsum()
```

However, this has a problem. When there are gains and there are withdraws, the withdrawal would need to withdraw from the gains before it effects that principal. The output of the above has the mistake in the result below (row 8 and 10):

```
    Type    Amount  Capital Principal
0   D       10      10      10
1   D       10      20      20
2   W       -5      15      15
3   D       10      25      25
4   G       5       30      25
5   G       5       35      25
6   G       5       40      25
7   L       -5      35      25
8   W       -10     25      15   <- should stays at 25
9   G       10      35      15   <- now wrong because of above
10  W       -25     10      -10  <- error escalades
11  G       25      35      -10
12  L       -30     5       -10
```

I am able to get the desire result by doing the following, but it seems a bit ugly.
Wondering if there some easier or short hand way. I'd imagine this is a common calculation in finance.

```
df['Principal'] = np.nan
currentPrincipal = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Type'] == 'D'):
        #row['Principal'] = currentPrincipal + row['Amount']
        df.loc[index, 'Principal'] = currentPrincipal + row['Amount']
    elif (row['Type'] == 'W' and row['Capital'] <= currentPrincipal):
        #row['Principal'] = row['Capital']
        df.loc[index, 'Principal'] = row['Capital']
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Principal'] = currentPrincipal
        
    currentPrincipal = df.loc[index, 'Principal']
```

I was not successful in trying to use `apply` as we have a dependency on the previous result of Principal that needs to be carried forward.
Correct result:

```
    Type    Amount  Capital Principal
0   D       10      10      10
1   D       10      20      20
2   W       -5      15      15
3   D       10      25      25
4   G       5       30      25
5   G       5       35      25
6   G       5       40      25
7   L       -5      35      25
8   W       -10     25      25
9   G       10      35      25
10  W       -25     10      10
11  G       25      35      10
12  L       -30     5       10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# calculate cumulative withdrawals
w = df['Amount'].where(df['Type'].eq('W')).cumsum()

# calculate cumulative deposits
d = df['Amount'].where(df['Type'].eq('D'), 0).cumsum()

# calculate cumulative gain & loss
g = df['Amount'].where(df['Type'].isin(['G', 'L']), 0).cumsum()

# calculate principal = deposit + net_withdrawal(if any)
df['Principal'] =  d + (g + w).where(lambda x: x < 0).ffill().fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
   Type  Amount  Capital  Principal
0     D      10       10       10.0
1     D      10       20       20.0
2     W      -5       15       15.0
3     D      10       25       25.0
4     G       5       30       25.0
5     G       5       35       25.0
6     G       5       40       25.0
7     L      -5       35       25.0
8     W     -10       25       25.0
9     G      10       35       25.0
10    W     -25       10       10.0
11    G      25       35       10.0
12    L     -30        5       10.0
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. Does look cleaner. Do you know the relative performance of this? Seems like a lot of iterations to calculate all the cumulative sums?

Comment: @phandinhlan I feel this should be faster as `cumsum` operation is inherently vectorised in numpy. But I guess you can test this on your data to see the results for yourself..

Comment: My concern is that `cumsum()` was called 3 times compared to the single for loop, not that each `cumsum()` isn't fast.